# HTML 5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, firefox3.6

I hear that Firefox 3.6 adds support for the HTML local file API ([Announcement here](http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2010/01/21/firefox-3-6-release/)).

Does this mean that I can access local files from javascript?

Can anyone point me to examples for reading / writing local files?

I would love to be able to read / write simple text files.

Comment: That's a mistake in the announcement, though. The File API has very little to do with HTML5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only files you can access are files dropped from the desktop or files that has been selected from an `<input/>` tag. See the demo I've written here: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/uploading-files-with-xmlhttprequest/

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't allow accessing arbitrary local files.  It's more of a file upload improvement.  For instance, you can have some Javascript accept a drag-and-drop file initiated by the user of the browser.

You can find the W3C spec on it [here](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the demo at [hacks.mozilla.org](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/uploading-files-with-xmlhttprequest/).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a (mozilla-specific explanation of the API on the [Mozilla Development Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write to local file system, but the user must complete a 'save as...' action. For now, no direct access to client file system. Take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-file-writer-api-20110419/#examples)