# How to develop Desktop Apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, desktop-application

First, I'm not interested in doing this professionally. I am a web developer, a coworker of mine recently left for Spotify and said he will be working mostly in JavaScript for the Spotify Desktop app. He said it uses "Chrome frame" and everything inside is done like a web app (HTML/JS/CSS).

As a web developer who never built anything for Desktop, this is great news. If I can use the technologies I already know and implement them inside some sort of a "frame" and still be able to build a windows or better yet cross platform app.

I know I didn't mention anything about the database, but even a simple hello world desktop app with web technologies would be great to get going.

So how does one go about this? Exactly what do I need/need to know?

Comment: It should be noted that there are at least two non-exclusive tiers of web-app-iness. One would be client-side, single-page application style apps, and one would be an app that maintains state with a database or something. (Of course, the best apps are both.) You can learn how to do one without learning much about the other.

Comment: Another related thread here [Can you do Desktop Development using JavaScript?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript

Regards,

Ben

Comment: You do it wrong. Web is not designed to desktop app. Period.If you want you can use QML/QtQuick, which is a good trade-off (but it remains desktop, not web !)

Comment: similar here： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109399/can-you-do-desktop-development-using-javascript

Comment: http://electron.atom.io

Comment: @tuple_cat - I guess a lot of people didn't see this because it's only a comment. Knowing that even "VS Code" is built with electron is great. Thanks!

Comment: Slack uses MacGap https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap1 and https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap2

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend? o.O

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You may start with Titanium for desktop dev.  Also you may have a look at **[Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)**.  It's basically a web browser control based on chromium.

It's written in C++ so you can do all the low level OS stuff you want(Growl, tray icons, local file access, com ports, etc) in your container app, and then all the application logic and gui in html/javascript.  It allows you to intercept any http request to either serve local resources or perform some custom action.  For example, a request to http://localapp.com/SetTrayIconState?state=active could be intercepted by the container and then call the C++ function to update the tray icon.

It also allows you to create functions that can be called directly from JavaScript.

It's very difficult to debug JavaScript directly in CEF.  There's no support for anything like Firebug.

You may also try **[AppJS.com](http://appjs.com/)** (Helps to build Desktop Applications. for Linux, Windows and Mac using HTML, CSS and JavaScript)

Also, as pointed out by @Clint, the team at **[brackets.io](http://brackets.io/)** (Adobe) created an awesome shell using Chromium Embedded Framework that makes it much easier to get started. It is called the brackets shell: [github.com/adobe/brackets-shell](http://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell) Find out more about it here: [clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell](http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell)

Comment: CEF has chrome dev tools built in it so you can use it to debug js. AppJS also has low level access to OS using nodejs APIs.

Comment: The team at Bracket.io (Adobe) created an awesome shell using Chromium Embedded Framework that makes it much easier to get started. It is called the brackets shell: https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/  Find out more about it here: http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell/

Comment: I'm currently using CEF, and Eclipse as dev tools, and it's possible to link CEF to Chrome Developper Tools by passing --remote-debugging-port=8080 to the run configurations for program args, then go to localhost:8080 in Chrome. So please remove the part - t's very difficult to debug JavaScript directly in CEF. There's no support for anything like Firebug. -

Comment: Also, I'm starting to develop Kontena コンテナ https://github.com/jhg/kontena for development a solution for Win32, Linux, Unix like, Mac and SmartPhone that will be based in CEF, PhoneGap, Backet.io of Adobe, AppJS, etc. It is so unstable and only is a prototype now for get a MVP, is writed in Python for test concept but will be translate code to C++/C with QT5 (now use QT4) and when be in C++/C start translation for mobil support.

Comment: @JHG good job.. Let us know when its officially released and bug-fixed

Answer (score 34):

## NW.js

(Previously known as node-webkit)

I would suggest **[NW.js](http://nwjs.io/)** if you are familiar with Node or experienced with JavaScript.

> NW.js is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js.
>
> Features
>
> - Apps written in modern HTML5, CSS3, JS and WebGL
> - Complete support for Node.js APIs and all its third party modules.
> - Good performance: Node and WebKit run in the same thread: Function calls are made straightforward; objects are in the same heap and can just reference each other
> - Easy to package and distribute apps
> - Available on Linux, Mac OS X and Windows

You can find the NW.js repo [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), and a good introduction to NW.js [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296). If you fancy learning [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) I would recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5511507/1724097) SO post with a lot of good links.

Comment: Seconded. Great tool.

Comment: But this cant be distributed between people without asking them to install node and node-webkit, right?

Comment: @JānisGruzis No, you shipped your app [with NW.js binaries](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/v0.13.0-rc3/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/).

Answer (score 27):

> <strike>[Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) makes it easy to use HTML UI in your C++ or .NET app</strike>

## Update

My previous answer is now outdated. These days you would be crazy not to look into using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) for this. Many popular desktop apps have been developed on top of it.

Answer (score 16):

NOTE: [AppJS](https://github.com/appjs/appjs) is deprecated and not recommended anymore.

Take a look at [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) instead.

Comment: This appears to have been deprecated by the appjs creators

Comment: @DanEsparza thanks, I improved my answer

Answer (score 9):

It seems the solutions for HTML/JS/CSS desktop apps are in no short supply.

One solution I have just come across is TideSDK: http://www.tidesdk.org/, which seems very promising, looking at the documentation.

You can develop with Python, PHP or Ruby, and package it for Mac, Windows or Linux.

Comment: Looked promising, but not being developed anymore it looks like. The core team is now working on something call TideKit but it takes forever for them to release it - PLUS it will cost money :(

Comment: Yes, pity. It did look promising at the time I answered though. I guess that's one reason why they frown on questions regarding recommendations for stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to burst your bubble but *Spotify desktop client* is [just a Webkit-based browser](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/#webbrowserengine). Of course it exposes specific additional functionality, but it's only able to run JS and render HTML/CSS because it has a JS engine as well as a Chromium rendering engine. This does not help you with coding a client-side web-app and deploying to multiple platforms.

What you're looking for is similar to [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) - a framework that allows for HTML5 apps to be natively deployed to iOS, Android and Blackberry devices. It basically acts as an intermediary between certain API calls and device-specific functionality available.

I have no experience with [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), bit it appears to be doing exactly that - and get very favourable reviews online. You should give it a go (unless you wanted to go back to 1999 and roll with [MS HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) ;)

Comment: It uses webkit for application but the main soft is not based on html/js

Answer (score 1):

I know for there's [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) and [Prism](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism) (there are others, that's the one I used to use) that let you load a website into what looks like a standalone app.

In Chrome, you can create desktop shortcuts for websites. (you do that from within Chrome, you can't/shouldn't package that with your app) Chrome Frame is different:

> Google Chrome Frame is a plug-in designed for Internet Explorer based
>   on the open-source Chromium project; it brings Google Chrome's open
>   web technologies to Internet Explorer.

You'd need to have some sort of wrapper like that for your webapp, and then the rest is the web technologies you're used to. You can use HTML5 [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store data while the app is offline. I think you might even be able to work with SQLite.

I don't know how you would go about accessing OS specific features, though. What I described above has the same limitations as any "regular" website. Hopefully this gives you some sort of guidance on where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can build Javascript apps with Adobe AIR… http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

Answer (score 0):

CEF offers lot of flexibility and options for customisation. But if the intent is to develop quickly node-webkit is also a good option. Node-web kit also offers ability to call node modules directly from DOM.

If there aren't any native modules to integrate Node-Webkit can offer better mileage. With native modules C/C++ or even C# it is better with CEF.