# Can you use jQuery in WPF Applications?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, wpf

I have been creating a WPF Application over the past few months and I wanted to add abit of animation to my Application.I have been told before that jQuery is a good Javascript library to use for animation.

The problem is after looking around abit there are not many things on the internet that lets me know if this is possible.

I'm very new to jQuery so i wont know much. If jQuery isnt possible in WPF, what is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So technically you can use jQuery in WPF. Just not in a way that you might necessarily like. 
With the [web browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) you could load html, css, and javascript from local or remote sources.

Please note* I did not make this example up from scratch. It comes from [this site](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/840/working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf)

in xaml add the control

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wbMain" Margin="30"></WebBrowser>
```

and in code

```
wbMain.Navigate(new Uri("c:/MyFileThatUsesJqueryAndHasJqueryAsARef.htm"));
```

Additionally communication between the two is also possible but does require a bit of work. 
You would have to create a com visible class with full trust security

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ObjectForScriptingHelper
{
    Mainwindow mExternalWPF;
    public ObjectForScriptingHelper(Window1w)
    {
        this.mExternalWPF = w;
    }
    public void InvokeMeFromJavascript(string jsscript)
    {
        this.mExternalWPF.tbMessageFromBrowser.Text = string.Format("Message :{0}", jsscript);
    }

}
```

With that you would create an instance in your class and access it via javascript like

```
<input type="text" id="txtMessage" />
<input type="button" value="InvokeMe" onclick="javascript:window.external.InvokeMeFromJavascript(document.getElementById('txtMessage').value);" />
```

Please look at the article for even more stuff you can do.

**Caveats**

- This is more than likely not the best way to go for a new desktop application. If its just a matter of using an existing tool out of familiarity then I'd consider other avenues of approach like learning WPF or looking to something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232784/how-to-develop-desktop-apps-using-html-css-javascript) or [one](http://enyojs.com/) [of](http://appjs.com/) [these](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit/)

If in fact you are out to use as much of an existing code base coded in html and javascript with with an offline app you could utilize this approach to recycle your existing code base by all means look at this or method or one of the other methods mentioned like using [WPF animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer and a solution to my issue. I Still don't know weather jQuery or Animation would be better in XAML.

Comment: In my experience, I'd say use xaml and expression blend (There should be a free version now). I http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296376(v=expression.40).aspx

Comment: The other route is more than likely going to be filled with a great deal of pain

Comment: The example code has a bunch of syntax errors and it's unclear what the intention was. Ex: `public ObjectForScriptingHelper(Window1w)`

Comment: I don't see a "bunch of syntax errors" . If you see something specific feel free to point it out or edit it if you have the rep. I did see one escaped tag for the closing WebBrowser tag and I fixed that. 

If you do not like the class name feel free to put a better name in the comments and I'd be happy to change it. 

 As far as the intent... OP wanted to know if there was a way to have javascript and wpf communicate and this is a way to that to happen. Please elaborate on your comment and give me some context before the downvote. Thanks