# WPF Circular Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, wpf-controls, countdowntimer

I am newbie to WPF. 
I want to create a circular countdown timer in WPF can anyone guide me in this regards with some sample code?

I found some jquery circular timers on internet how can i use it in WPF ?

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Slick-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Plugin-Classy-Countdown/

Comment: it would be better if i get the similar jquery timer in WPF

Answer (score 0):

The jquery framework was designed to work inside browsers, where WPF is not.
You could however use the [web browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) but it isn't the recommended approach.
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482232/can-you-use-jquery-in-wpf-applications) for a related answer.
A better solution would be to create/find a circular timer control to use in your application.