# How to disable keyboard input in DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using Extended WPF Toolkit and I need to disable keyboard input for TextBox (or whatever it is) in DateTimePicker. I've already tried this:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding DateStart, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CustomDatePicker}">
    <xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
</xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

For both `TargetType="TextBox"` and `TargetType="DatePickerTextBox"` - they don't work.

How can I disable keyboard input (without making it `ReadOnly` - I still need to be able to pick date and time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `AllowTextInput` property.

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Height="20" Width="200" AllowTextInput="False" />
```

Comment: `DateTimePicker` doesn't seem to have `AllowTextInput` property.

Comment: It's strange, maybe it was added in some ot the new versions of Extended Toolkit. I've tested on 2.6.0.0 version

Comment: So if it is possible you can try to update Extendeded Toolkit.

Comment: Ok, I've updated Extended WPF Toolkit version - there is `AllowTextInput` now. Thank you everyone.

Comment: The property AllowTextInput has been added to class InputBase on v2.4 (Feb. 13, 2015).

Answer (score 1):

Your `TargetType` is wrong. You need to change your `TargetType` like below:

```
TargetType="{xctk:Type toolkitPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox}"
```

**Note :** Make sure you are having reference to the `toolkitPrimitives namespace`

**e.g** `xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit`

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea rows=3 cols=20></textarea>​

$("textarea").keydown(false);
```

=========2nd option=======

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly='true'>
```

=======3rd option===============

```
$('#rush_needed_by_english').keydown(function() {

    return false;
});
```

Comment: OP asking about `WPF` solution. Your solution is for `asp.net` and `MVC`.

Comment: Okay... is it not possible using jquery or some javascript in WPF..?

Comment: It's possible but very difficult. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482232/can-you-use-jquery-in-wpf-applications

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Rahul's answer works or not, because I have slightly different answer.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}">
   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Nope. It still allows input.