# Skills needed for a desktop application development

Tags: web, desktop-application

I'm currently working as a web developer. I'm curious to know if similar technologies are used for desktop application development. Morever, can we write a web app and distribute it with a open source browser so that it feels like a desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/)

> If you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a
>   framework for creating native applications with web technologies like
>   JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can
>   focus on the core of your application.

This question is answered many times, do check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12232784/2644202). It also lists other options in this matter.